# Double execution of functions in insert statement when using returning clause on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c, oracle21c

We found a bug on Oracle DB version 21.3 (the same was also tested on 19.3 version). If you use functions inside insert statement and return values using returning clause the result is that the function you are calling inside the insert statemet executes TWICE!!!

Below is a sample using a function that creates a next value for a sequence. I know you can use ".nextval" directly (and as shown works fine), but that is just a sample to demonstrate double execution of functions. I could be using any other function and would be executed TWICE (for example calculating something).

You can test how it works using this sample:

```
create sequence seq_1;
create sequence seq_2;
create table test1000 (id number, a varchar2(4004));
create table test1001 (id number, a varchar2(1001));
create or replace function testfun return number is
  v_a number;
begin
  select seq_1.nextval into v_a from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('FUNCTION RETURNS SEQ_1 VALUE: '||v_a);
  return v_a;
end;
/
```

You can test this if you execute this:

```
declare
  v_a varchar2(100);
begin
  insert into test1000(id, a) values (seq_2.nextval, 'SEQ_1:'||testfun) returning a into v_a;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_a);
  insert into test1001(id, a) values (seq_2.nextval, 'SEQ_1:'||testfun) returning a into v_a;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_a);
end;
/
```

It will output:

```
FUNCTION RETURNS SEQ_1 VALUE: 1
SEQ_1:1
FUNCTION RETURNS SEQ_1 VALUE: 2
FUNCTION RETURNS SEQ_1 VALUE: 3
SEQ_1:3
```

You can see the double execution hapenned in the second insert. The data in the table test1001 has value 2, but the value returned in variable v_a is different (value 3). Double execution didn't happen in the first insert, but in the second. I believe this is because the second table has the field "a" with a varchar2 with max size higher than 4000 and I believe this has something to do how oracle handles extended varchar2 type (MAX_STRING_SIZE is extended in our DB).

I reported this bug to Oracle. I will update this when I get a response from them...

Comment: Cannot replicate on [Oracle 11gR2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f473cada810e89a400210ceb640f2b0) or [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f473cada810e89a400210ceb640f2b0)

Comment: You can just use `v_a := seq_1.NEXTVAL;` in the function rather than having a context-switch to SQL and using `SELECT seq_1.NEXTVAL INTO v_a FROM DUAL;`.

Comment: I know the solution it just should't work like that. And yes it seem on the older versions it works. I found this when migrating from 11 to 19c.

Comment: Cannot replicate it on [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/) either (which is running Oracle 19.8.0.0.0).

Comment: they probably don't have MAX_STRING_SIZE set to EXTENDED. I'm just guessing... Or try using varchar2 with more than 4000.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the upper sample is simple. Just use ".nextval" directly. If you have any different function the solution is that you execute the function (and save the result in a variable) before using it in the insert statement like this:

```
declare
  v_a varchar2(100);
  v_seq_id number;
begin
  v_seq_id := testfun;
  insert into test1000(id, a) values (seq_2.nextval, 'SEQ_1:'||v_seq_id) returning a into v_a;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_a);
  v_seq_id := testfun;
  insert into test1001(id, a) values (seq_2.nextval, 'SEQ_1:'||v_seq_id) returning a into v_a;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_a);
end;
/
```

The result will be correct:

```
FUNCTION RETURNS SEQ_1 VALUE: 1
SEQ_1:1
FUNCTION RETURNS SEQ_1 VALUE: 2
SEQ_1:2
```

Oracle opened a bug - [Bug 33847911](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?_afrLoop=110679828518630&parent=SrDetailText&sourceId=3-27842452271&id=33847911&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13lkfcf2ln_141)